# How I can create polymorhic method Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I try to create some [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vlutesevich-typescript-types?embed=1&file=src/app/registration.service.ts)

How I can write updateStepData method, 
that will change stepOneData if get data with type stepOneData
and will change stepTwoData if get data with type stepOneData?

```
  updateStepData(data: StepOneData | StepTwoData): void {
     Object.keys(data).map(key => {
       // if (data instanceof StepOneData) {
          this.stepOneData[key] = data[key];
       // } 

       // if (data instanceof StepTwoData) {
          this.stepTwoData[key] = data[key];
       // } 
     });
  }
```

I have tried use instanceof operator but here it's not work.

Comment: from where is the key variable coming? If you say it doesn't work, what doesn't work, and what behavior are you expecting?

Comment: it should be working, please post the input of your function

Comment: I checked the type using `data.constructor.name`, and your type is just Object. So you are passing the wrong type somewhere down the line.

Comment: the sence in data variable. I get it in subscribe: stepForm.valueChanges.subscribe( data=> { this.updateStepData(data) }). In that place I can create new StepOneData() and manually copy values from data to this new object, and than insanceof will work. May it's decision. But it interesting how we can manage type of data variable in subcribe() automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found this method in your Step1Component :

```
onFormChanges(): void {
    this.stepOneForm.valueChanges
      .subscribe((data: StepOneData) => {

        this.registrationService.updateStepData(data);
      });
}
```

change it like this :

```
onFormChanges(): void {
    this.stepOneForm.valueChanges
      .subscribe((data: StepOneData) => {

        const stepOneData = new StepOneData();

        stepOneData.firstName = data.firstName;
        stepOneData.firstName = data.lastName;      

        this.registrationService.updateStepData(stepOneData);
      });
}
```

do the same to your Step2Component

now u can use instanceof as u wrote in your code :

```
   if (data instanceof StepOneData) {
    this.stepOneData[key] = data[key];
  } 

  if (data instanceof StepTwoData) {
     this.stepTwoData[key] = data[key];
  }
```

=========================================

to make a readable code u can add constrcutor to your StepOneData and StepTwoData classes to init their properties like this :

```
export class StepTwoData {

  constructor(public city:string,public state:string){}

}
```

and in your components :

```
 onFormChanges(): void {
    this.stepTwoForm.valueChanges
      .subscribe((data: StepTwoData) => {

        const stepTwoData= new StepTwoData(data.city,data.state);    

        this.registrationService.updateStepData(stepTwoData);
      });
}
```

==========================

***UPDATE :***

for better design i suggest u to write two method for each type . for instance "UpdateStepOneData" and "UpdateStepTwoData" .

and if there is shared logic in these methods put it in a method named "UpdateStepData" .

```
UpdateStepOneData(data:StepOneData){

       // Custom Code goes here

       UpdateStepData(...); // Shared Logic goes here

}

UpdateStepTwoData(data:StepTwoData){

       // Custom Code goes here

       UpdateStepData(...); // Shared Logic goes here

}
```

Comment: cool, thank you @Soroush_Neshat. This is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: And how do you @Soroush_Neshat think, may it was better to do two methods: first for updateStep1Data() and second updateStep2Data() instead of this univesal updateStepData() ?. Which is way more competent?

Comment: Or else I can create updateStepData() with second parameter and when invoke this method pass step = 1, or step = 2... And then use it info inside method.

Comment: there is a better solution . Currently i am in bus and cant type codes  . I will share it when i got home :)

Comment: @ValeryLutsevich sorry man i totally forgot to share my solution . i'm so sorry .

i added the solution to the answer above